# In magento 2.0.7 how to redirect the custom module admin system config

Tags: configuration, custom, redirect, magento-2.0.7

In magento 2.0.7 how we can make redirect our custom module system config after successfully saved data

For example want to redirect one particular section

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 namespace [Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class [YourClass] implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $_responseFactory;
protected $_url;

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
) {
    $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_url = $url;
}

public function execute(Observer $observer) {
    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
    $currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $currentWebsiteId = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    $RedirectUrl= $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('_current' => array('section name here', 'website here', 'store here)));
    $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($RedirectUrl)->sendResponse();
    die();
}
}
```